# The code crashed in runtime , initialization is compiled, member variable points to random address and cant access it

Tags: c++, initialization

```
/*
 Constructor initializing a string pointer
*/
    class Person {
    public:

        Person(string name) :pName(new string(name)) {
            //pName = new string(name);
        }
        ~Person() { delete pName; }
        void printName() { cout << *pName << endl; }
    private:
        string* pName;
    };
    
    int main() {
        vector<Person> persons;
        persons.push_back(Person("p1"));
        persons.front().printName();
        cout<<"Good bye"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) by adding definition of copy constructor and assignment operator to avoid troubles on copying.

Comment: Please review [ask] for advice on how to write a good question.

Comment: Does the string variable really need to be a pointer to a string? If you had a string member instead you could use the rule of zero.

Answer (score 1):

I might not have this entirely correct but the reason this is happening is as follows..
`Person("p1")` creates a temporary person with a pointer to the string `"p1"`.  `persons.push_back()` copies that object into the vector.  This is only a shallow copy so the new object's pointer will point to the memory location of the temporary object's string which gets destroyed so you're accessing invalid memory.

You can do `persons.emplace_back("p1");` which creates the object in place in the vector so no copying takes place; however, as the comments point out, if you are managing memory yourself then you need to apply the rule of 3 and implement copy and assignment constructors as well as the destructor.